# Sending Ajax request to call a python function through jquery

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I am trying to send a request to call a python method in my python script.
Server Side:
I am using flask ,so the server is running on port 5000.It has a file called helloflask.py which look like

```
#helloflas.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hello",methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello():
    return "Comming Here"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000,debug=True)
```

Client Side:
Independent HTML outside of flask which is sending the ajax request.

```
<!--ajax call-->
<script>
function findAppartment() {

                $.ajax({
                url: "https://127.0.0.1:5000/hello/",
                type: "get",
                contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                   // $('#blurg').html(response).fadeIn(1500);
                }
            });

         }
    </script>
```

when the request is made,I get the following error.It hits the server and gives the following error:

```
Error : code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\xa1\x01\x00\x00\x9d\x03\x02Q\xd8\xc0O+\x8f\xa6\x16F\x9a\x94\x90|$\x11\xd3\xd8\x15\x04$\xe4\xb4>\xc0\x0e\xe3\xa0h\xea\x07\x00\xc5\x00\x00H\xc0')
```

I tried many things but things don't seem to be working.Could any one help???Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `/hello` and `/hello/` aren't the same route. Also, where are you getting that error message from?

Comment: the error message comes on the server and i tried both /hello and /hello/ and both are giving the same problem. I tried through the browser using the same url and it works fine.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message? Is it coming from the Flask development server? Also, are you sure it's `https`?

Comment: My bad....the problem was much simpler ...i was using https instead of http,